# SweetAlert of React always delete/edit last item of a dynamic list

Tags: reactjs, list, sweetalert

I'm using React in a list of dynamically items (added with an input and a button in a form) and each item has 2 buttons: to EDIT the name of item and to DELETE the item. I'm using the react-bootstrap-sweetalert library:

DELETE:

```
<SweetAlert
  show={isModalDeleteOpen}
  info
  title="Delete item?"
  onConfirm={() => handleDeleteItem(item.id)}
  onCancel={closeDeleteModal}
>
I did it!
</SweetAlert>
```

EDIT:

```
                    <SweetAlert
                        show={isModalEditOpen}
                        input
                        showCancel
                        cancelBtnBsStyle="light"
                        title="Item's name"
                        placeHolder="Write something"
                        onConfirm={(response) => {
                            handleEdit(response, item.id)
                        }}
                        onCancel={closeModalEdit}
                        >
                        Change the item's name:
                    </SweetAlert>
```

Example:

```
> Item 1            - ButtonEdit  -  ButtonDelete 
> Item 2            - ButtonEdit  -  ButtonDelete 
> ...
```

The problem is that the last item is always deleted/edited, even if the delete/edit button for the first item is clicked. Debugging, I have seen that the "item.id" that reaches the function is the wrong one, but I don't know why. Can someone help me? Thanks!

PD: Both SweetAlerts are added into the creation of each 'li', so that there is modal for each 'li', but it doesn't seem to be the solution:

```
items.map((item) =>
> li key={item.id}
   > item name
   > edit button
   > delete button
   > SweetAlert (edit button)
   > SweetAlert (delete button)
>/li
```

...

```
const handleEdit = (newValue, id) => {
    const editToDoAction = {
        type: 'edit',
        payload: id,
        name: newValue
    }
    dispatch(editToDoAction);
}
```

...

```
case 'edit':
        return state.map( item => {
            if (item.id === action.payload) { 
                item.name = action.name;
            }
            return item;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Its difficult to answer with only these fragments. A full sample of code would be more helpful so the flow of the code can be tracked

Comment: @HassanNaqvi I've added more code in case it's helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be using the same boolean state to display all the alerts. Meaning the `isModalDeleteOpen` and `isModalEditOpen` are shared by all the alerts.

This would mean if `isModalDeleteOpen` is `true`, all the delete alerts would be displayed and probably the last one is stacked on top of all others.

The state of the component that would make sure that is the problem is not mentioned though so this is unfortunately a partial guess.

The solution would be to have a seperate state `isModalDeleteOpen` state for each alert